# React handle data from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm pretty new in react and also material-ui and I'm trying to get my hands dirty. I'm trying to pass some data from child to parent component in order to update the parent state of *delivery-at*    the new date is being printed on the console, but the state doesn't updates.

```
class TaskForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          formData: {
            delivery_at: null,
          }
        };
        this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
      }
    handleDateChange = (event, date) => {
        this.setState({
          formData: {
            delivery_at: date
          }
        });
        console.log(date);
      };
      render() {
        const { formData, submitted } = this.state; 
        return (
          <div>
            <ValidatorForm
              style={formStyle}
              ref="form"
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            >
              <DateCalendar //Datepicker child component
                name="delivery_at"
                value={formData.delivery_at}
                handleChange={this.handleDateChange}
                validators={["required"]}
              />
              <RaisedButton
               onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}
               type="submit"
               label={
               (submitted && "Your form is submitted!") ||
               (!submitted && "Submit")
               }
               disabled={submitted}
               backgroundColor="pink"
          />
        </ValidatorForm>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Child component

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "material-ui/DatePicker";

class DateCalendar extends React.Component {

render() {
    // const{ delivery_at } = this.state;
    return (
      <DatePicker
        hintText="Delivery At"
        name={this.props.name}
        value={this.props.delivery_at}
        autoOk={true}
        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default DateCalendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

edit ** 
Hang on - i'll figure this out

I'm not sure but try changing you method to look like this (it may be an issue with the value of "this":

```
      handleDateChange(event, date){
        this.setState({
          formData: {
            delivery_at: date
          }
        });
        console.log(date);
      };
```

for further debugging try logging state in the callback:

```
      handleDateChange(event, date){
        this.setState({
          formData: {
            delivery_at: date
          }
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state)
        });
        console.log(date);
      };
```